# Python-opencv Movement detection

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, video-capture

Hi I have followed this tutorial with the code found here https://github.com/HackerShackOfficial/Smart-Security-Camera
How do I use this on a usb camera on a windows 10 laptop? I have tried to convert this with videocapture(0) but I cant get it right someone please have a look for me!

The software runs through a raspberry pi camera board and when movement is detected it screen shots she camera and emails me and the camera feed is hosted on an ip server with flask on my router.

Comment: Have you tried to implement any of those features?

Comment: Yes I have I have tried

Comment: Where is the code you have written?  If you have indeed tried, post the code in your question so people can help you.

Comment: here I followed the tutorial here's the (code below) but this is written for the raspberry pi zero how do I port this to windows 10 usb cam with videocapture(0) belowhttps://github.com/HackerShackOfficial/Smart-Security-Camera

Comment: "*I have tried to convert this with videocapture(0) but I cant get it right*"  
Show what you have tried so far so that we can see what is going wrong.  We need to see **your** code, not someone else's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lol hasn't worked will try again thanks to every one who helped

Answer (score 0):

I dont know, why your program doesn't work, but I have another solution for surveillance system on Raspberry Pi based on software **Motion**

It works with almost any camera (USB/IP,RPi Camera) and it is very good scalable.

You can use events like onMotion() and call other programs (upload video to FTP, send SMS, ...)

Here is good starting point: https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/raspberry-pi-security-camera-livestream-setup/

Comment: hi Koxo thanks for your reply. I will take a look. But what Im trying to do is run my code on a windows 10 laptop with a usb camera so theres no raspberry pi involved.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad.